# jqGrid - Having text boxes along with sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid, editing

[Apparently](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/edit-row-sort-problem/) when editing a row, sorting via column headings is disabled.

We want to have a grid where a text box always appears in each row where users can enter data and then hit a submit button.

We [figured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901560/set-up-jqgrid-so-all-rows-are-editable) out how to display a text box for each row BUT the problem is that this disables sorting.  Any way to do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented this with a custom formatter that just outputs the HTML `<INPUT...>` elements